# How to display custom field on woocommerce order item details template?

Tags: php, loops, woocommerce

I'm having some trouble trying to display the field I have created in the table of the order items details template of woocommerce and i'm not very knowledgeable in PHP. I have created a field called sessions and registered it as a product post type.

[image]

[image]

Once a user purchase a product I want the custom field(sessions) to also be displayed.

Here is the template of the view-order of woocommerce.

```
<?php
/**
 * Order Item Details
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/order/order-details-item.php.
 *
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

if ( ! apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_visible', true, $item ) ) {
    return;
}
?>
<tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_class', 'order_item', $item, $order ) ); ?>">
    <td class="product-name">

        <?php
            $is_visible = $product && $product->is_visible();

            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', $is_visible ? sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', get_permalink( $item['product_id'] ), $item['name'] ) : $item['name'], $item, $is_visible );
            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_quantity_html', ' <strong class="product-quantity">' . sprintf( '&times; %s', $item['qty'] ) . '</strong>', $item );

            do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_start', $item_id, $item, $order );

            $order->display_item_meta( $item );
            $order->display_item_downloads( $item );

            do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', $item_id, $item, $order );
        ?>
    </td>
    <td class="product-total">
        <?php echo $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item ); ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php if ( $show_purchase_note && $purchase_note ) : ?>
<tr class="product-purchase-note">
    <td colspan="3"><?php echo wpautop( do_shortcode( wp_kses_post( $purchase_note ) ) ); ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I have no idea or understanding where I would insert `the_field(sessions)` to display it on the checkout

Comment: edit the template file `wp-content\themes\--themename--\woocommerce\checkout\form-checkout.php` and echo the field there. Are you using acf?

Comment: than you can use [get_field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) `$field= get_field( "sessions", idofproduct);`

Comment: but how can you get product custom field in checkout form as products can be multiple.

Comment: that is what to know. Trying to research how I can display the field with multiple products on checkout

Comment: You can do that in 2 ways. In one way; you may display it beneath the Product Name (a little Uglier). In the other way; you can display the Session in its own column but you also have to edit another file too. Both solutions were posted below. Try if any works for you...

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach and see what you get:

```
    <?php
        /**
         * Order Item Details
         *
         * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/order/order-details-item.php.
         *
         */

        if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
            exit;
        }

        if ( ! apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_visible', true, $item ) ) {
            return;
        }
        $sessions   = "sessions";       //DEFINE THE SESSIONS STRING...
    ?>
    <tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_class', 'order_item', $item, $order ) ); ?>">
        <td class="product-name">

            <?php
                $is_visible = $product && $product->is_visible();

                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', $is_visible ? sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', get_permalink( $item['product_id'] ), $item['name'] ) : $item['name'], $item, $is_visible );
                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_quantity_html', ' <strong class="product-quantity">' . sprintf( '&times; %s', $item['qty'] ) . '</strong>', $item );

                do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_start', $item_id, $item, $order );

                $order->display_item_meta( $item );
                $order->display_item_downloads( $item );

                do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', $item_id, $item, $order );

                //PERHAPS RIGHT HERE ADD THE SESSION
                // IT IS IMPORTANT TO PASS IN THE PRODUCT-ID: $item['product_id'] SO THAT THE CORRECT FIELD IS RETRIEVED.
                echo "<p class='session'><strong>" .__("Session: ", "ttd") . "</strong><em class='session-value'>" . get_field($sessions, $item['product_id']) . "</em></p>";
                //OR THIS WAY
                echo "<p class='session'><strong>" .__("Session: ", "ttd") . "</strong><em class='session-value'>" . get_post_meta($item['product_id'], $sessions, true) . "</em></p>";
            ?>
        </td>
        <td class="product-total">
            <?php echo $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item ); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php if ( $show_purchase_note && $purchase_note ) : ?>
        <tr class="product-purchase-note">
            <td colspan="3"><?php echo wpautop( do_shortcode( wp_kses_post( $purchase_note ) ) ); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Alternatively, you could also do it like so:

```
    <?php
        /**
         * Order Item Details
         *
         * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/order/order-details-item.php.
         *
         */

        if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
            exit;
        }

        if ( ! apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_visible', true, $item ) ) {
            return;
        }
        $sessions   = "sessions";       //DEFINE THE SESSIONS STRING...
    ?>
    <tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_class', 'order_item', $item, $order ) ); ?>">
        <td class="product-name">

            <?php
                $is_visible = $product && $product->is_visible();

                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', $is_visible ? sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', get_permalink( $item['product_id'] ), $item['name'] ) : $item['name'], $item, $is_visible );
                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_quantity_html', ' <strong class="product-quantity">' . sprintf( '&times; %s', $item['qty'] ) . '</strong>', $item );

                do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_start', $item_id, $item, $order );

                $order->display_item_meta( $item );
                $order->display_item_downloads( $item );

                do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', $item_id, $item, $order );
            ?>
        </td>
        <td class="product-session">
            <!-- ALTERNATIVELY ADD THE SESSION RIGHT HERE ON A UNIQUE COLUMN-->
            <!-- IT IS IMPORTANT TO PASS IN THE PRODUCT-ID: $item['product_id'] SO THAT THE CORRECT FIELD IS RETRIEVED.-->
            <p class='session'>
                <strong><?php echo __("Session: ", "ttd"); ?></strong>
                <em class='session-value'><?php the_field($sessions, $item['product_id']); ?></em>
            </p>
            <!-- OR THIS WAY -->
            <p class='session'>
                <strong><?php echo __("Session: ", "ttd"); ?></strong>
                <em class='session-value'><?php echo get_post_meta($item['product_id'], $sessions, true); ?></em>
            </p>
        </td>
        <td class="product-total">
            <?php echo $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item ); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php if ( $show_purchase_note && $purchase_note ) : ?>
        <tr class="product-purchase-note">
            <td colspan="3"><?php echo wpautop( do_shortcode( wp_kses_post( $purchase_note ) ) ); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

But then, locate the File /templates/order/order-details.php. Select lines 1 through 35 and paste the code below over it:

```
<?php
/**
 * Order details
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/order/order-details.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you (the theme developer).
 * will need to copy the new files to your theme to maintain compatibility. We try to do this.
 * as little as possible, but it does happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will.
 * be bumped and the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author  WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 2.5.3
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

$show_purchase_note    = $order->has_status( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_purchase_note_order_statuses', array( 'completed', 'processing' ) ) );
$show_customer_details = is_user_logged_in() && $order->get_user_id() === get_current_user_id();
?>
<h2><?php _e( 'Order Details', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
<table class="shop_table order_details">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="product-name"><?php _e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        <th class="product-session"><?php _e( 'Session', 'your_ttd' ); ?></th> <!-- HERE WE ARE ADDING A COLUMN TO THE HEAD AS WELL TO MATCH...-->
        <th class="product-total"><?php _e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
```

Hope this helps...